# ConfigurationException is driving me nuts

Tags: c#, .net, exception, proxy

One of our clients reported having issues with our software. Upon further investigation it seems that a configuration exception is thrown when trying to initialize an `HttpWebRequest` object.

The exception message reads: `Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section.`

Looking for a solution online it seems there are a bunch of reasons for this error yet no solution I could find relates to my case.

The application and the .NET framework are both installed on the same drive which is the system drive. .NET 4 is installed and running ( I have re-installed it a couple of times to verify). And there are no proxies configured on the computer.

Here is my application config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

   <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="40" />
    </connectionManagement>
    <settings>
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

I have tried disabling the default proxy and default credentials but that did not solve it.

Some people suggested that it could be related to a malware, we ran Malwarebytes on the machine and it detected no threats.

What other options do I have? What other reasons that could raise such exception?

Comment: why supported runtime = 2.0 when you installed 4.0 ?

Comment: Does your exception has an inner exeception? Please copy-paste full exception .ToString() .

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino the application references some DLLs that are compiled against version 2.0. And there is no inner exception

Comment: Have you tried to remove the whole section <defaultProxy> ?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino yes I did and it resulted a WebException. I do not remember the full exception but it was `Unable to connect to the remote server`. I turned off Windows Firewall and the one on the router, I turned off the AV and still got the same issue.

Comment: Very strange... another test :)  Remove the children. Remove <proxy/>       <bypasslist/> and  <module/>   It's only a test. No idea if it really could help you. Sorry.

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino will try, however this being a client machine I cannot really ask for access just to try one simple thing. I will try to collect as much suggestions as possible and will let you know if any of them worked.